# How to know what libraries the `apt-get install` command installs [and optionally, how to locate these files]?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I took for granted the `apt-get install` command for too long.

How to know (other than reading the prompt) what files are being downloaded?

Cuz i can read the prompt when i'm installing these packages, but i won't remember in 4 months what i've read.

Also, how to know where these files are being downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to look up what files a package installs, you can use `apt-file show packagename`. It's not installed by default, so you'll have to install it first and then run `apt-file update`.

To list files for an installed package, you can use `dpkg -L packagename`.

Both commands will show the location of these files.